# Extending our language with a new function symbol

Tags: logic, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Given an arbitray first-order theory (not necessarily a set theory) and definable predicates $P(*)$ and $Q(*,*)$ in the language of that theory, if we adjoin a new function symbol $f$ together with the axiom
$$\forall x(P(x) \Rightarrow \exists y(Q(x,y))) \Rightarrow \forall x (P(x) \Rightarrow Q(x,f(x)))$$

is this extension necessarily conservative? Note that we're not requiring that the $y$ satisfying $Q(x,y)$ be unique in the antecedent.

Okay that was my first question. Supposing the answer is 'yes', my second question is this. Suppose our original first-order theory includes an axiom schema like [separation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification), or [replacement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_replacement) that runs over the definable predicates of our old language. Does the more general schema running over the definable predicates of the extended language also hold?

Finally, and this is probably a silly question, but supposing that both answers are yes, why doesn't this make the [Axiom of Choice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_choice) redundant?

Comment: Note that taking $P(x)$ to be $x\neq\varnothing$ and $Q(x,y)$ to be $y\in x$ we have that $f$ is a global choice function.

Comment: And once you have global choice, you can define $f$ for any other predicate by using that global choice function.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, so does that mean the answer is 'no'? If so, I find this surprising.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, I don't really get the thing about global choice since we're restricted to definable predicates. Can you please clarify? I'm also not entirely clear as to whether we can prove the usual axiom of choice. For instance, let $A$ denote a set of non-empty sets. Now adjoin $f$ such that for all $x \in A$ we have $f(x) \in x.$ Then if separation applies to our extended language (which I'm not sure it does), then the following set exists, so we have proved choice. $\{y \in \bigcup A \mid \exists x \in A : y = f(x)\}.$

Comment: Yes. This is a question that you need to address. Do you add replacement and separation for the new symbols? That's your choice as the one asking the question. Of course that if you don't add those then you can't prove the axiom of choice.

Comment: @Asaf, I see the original question was misleading. We begin with an arbitrary theory, like PA or ZFC or whatever. Then we adjoin $f$ together with that axiom, without expanding our axiom schemata or anything like that. My first question is, okay is this necessarily conservative? You have already answered my second question.

Comment: You should read about Skolem functions.

Comment: [Related MO question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/119397/notation-arbx)

Comment: @aws, that answers the question.

Comment: @aws: I remembered that thread but I couldn't find it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paradox is resolved [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/119397/notation-arbx) (thank you for the link, [aws](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/59213/aws)). In brief:

1. Yes, adjoining such an $f$ together with such an axiom is indeed conservative.
2. No, otherwise the axiom of choice would be provable in any set theory in which the axiom of union and the axiom schema of separation hold. So in particular, ZF would prove choice.
3. Since this question is predicated on the assumption that the answers to the previous two questions are 'yes', we may disregard it.